# Copy image from Finder and paste in macOs Catalyst app

Tags: swift, uipasteboard, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to get copy paste support for files in my Catalyst app. I've implemented drag and drop and paste works for images copied from a browser, or screenshot to clipboard etc. But when I copy an image file from Finder Pasteboard does not contain anything I know how to use. It seems like Pasteboard only contains a string with the filename, but not the full path or url.

If I check the itemProviders it doesn't seem to contain images of any type I can think of, like public/image, image/jpeg, etc.